# PowerShell: Iterate through all arrays and push a default value if empty

Tags: arrays, powershell, null, default-value, is-empty

There are multiple arrays, and their contents might or might not be empty. If any of these arrays are empty, I would like to add a default value to them.

I have tried wrapping all the arrays into a container array and using `Foreach-Object`, but the default value does not appear to be assigned.

```ps
#... 

$arr1 = @()
$arr2 = @("a","b")
$arr3 = @("c","d")

@($arr1, $arr2, $arr3 | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Count -le 0) {
        $_ = @("EMPTY")
    }
})

Write-Output $arr1

# ...
```

The empty array was not assigned

```ps
PS> $arr1
PS> <# NOTHING #>
```

Is it possible to set a default value for those arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to modify *variables*, not their *values*.
Therefore, you must enumerate variable *objects*, which you can obtain with [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable):

```bash
$arr1 = @()
$arr2 = @("a","b")
$arr3 = @("c","d")

Get-Variable arr* | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Value.Count -eq 0) {
    $_.Value = @("EMPTY")
  }
}

$arr1 # -> @('EMPTY')
```

---

Alternatively, consider maintaining your arrays in a single hashtable rather than in individual variables:

```bash
$arrays = [ordered] @{
  arr1 = @()
  arr2 = @("a","b")
  arr3 = @("c","d")
}

foreach ($key in @($arrays.Keys)) {
  if ($arrays.$key.Count -eq 0) {
    $arrays.$key = @('EMPTY')
  }
}

$arrays.arr1 # -> @('EMPTY')
```

Comment: Thank you, @mklement0, for this detailed reply.  Because my array names aren't consistent with a naming convention, I've used the second method of maintaining the arrays in a hashtable, which works just fine.